# What does .T means in np.vstack function?

Tags: python, numpy, vstack

I wonder what is the meaning of `.T` in  the function `np.vstack(array1, array2, array3).T`?

Comment: That `T` is outside it seems. This means vstack the arrays and then transpose the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ndarray.T: The transposed array.

Answer (score -3):

.T implies transpose of the stacked arrays.

Comment: Please be sure to check other existing answers to avoid giving the exact same answer again.